# Two different methods of formalizing(coding) object language

Tags: set-theory

In Devlin's Constructibility, the formulas are coded flatly. For example $\langle 0, 6, 0, 4, (2, 0), (3, 2), 1, 0, 5, (3, 4), (2, 1), 1, 1\rangle$ stands for $v_0 \in 2 \land 4 = v_1$. If we encode like this,

- We should also encode parenthesis. In Devlin's case, $0, 1$ stands for $(, )$ respectively.
- The length of code is varying so we should use sequences instead of tuples.
- When defining predicates like $\operatorname{Fml}, \vDash$, because integer addition is not $\Delta_0$, and $\land$ invokes addition, we should use a trick. For example Mathias pointed out that "$f$ is an attempt at addition" is $\Delta_0$, and provides sufficiently long attempt at addition instead of adding directly. The existence of sufficiently long attempt at addition raises the complexity of the formula to $\Delta_1$.

But in Devlin's Aspects of Constructibility, the formulas are coded recursively. For example $(4, ((2, ((0, 0), (1, 2))), (3, ((1, 4), (0, 1)))))$ stands for the same formula. If we encode like this,

- We don't need parenthesis.
- The length of code is fixed, so we can use tuples instead of sequences. In Devlin's case, only 2-tuple suffices.
- When defining predicates like $\operatorname{Fml}, \vDash$, we should use recursion. Devlin uses the notion of primitive recursive set functions to prove that they are $\Delta_1$.

Which method is better? For the former, Mathias proved that $\vDash$ is $\Delta_1^\mathsf{MW}$, where $\mathsf{MW}$ is much weaker than $\mathsf{KP}$. For the latter, Devlin only states that $\vDash$ is $\Delta_1^\mathsf{ZF}$. Is the latter way also adequate for developing the theory of constructibility in $\mathsf{KP}$?(for example, proving that $L$ is the minimal inner model of $\mathsf{KP}$)